# OLS and log-likelihood from scratch with Tensorflow

Tags: python, least-squares, tensorflow

I'm trying to code ordinary least square regression from scratch using Tensorflow and calculate the log likelihood. The results, however, are very different from the ones I get from my baselevel model, in which I'm using statsmodels.formula.api. Could you help me identify where am I making mistakes?

````
def ols_reg_loglike(self, X, Y):

    # Add bias term to input features
    X_with_bias = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X)), X))

    # Convert to TensorFlow tensors
    X_tf = tf.constant(X_with_bias, dtype=tf.float32)
    Y_tf = tf.constant(Y, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Compute coefficients using TensorFlow
    XT = tf.transpose(X_tf)
    XT_X_inv = tf.linalg.inv(tf.matmul(XT, X_tf))
    coefficients = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(XT_X_inv, XT), Y_tf)

    # Compute predictions
    Y_pred = tf.matmul(X_tf, coefficients)

    # Compute residuals
    residuals = Y_tf - Y_pred

    # Compute sum of squares of residuals
    SSR = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(residuals))

    # Compute degrees of freedom
    df = len(Y) - (X_with_bias.shape[1] - 1)

    # Compute variance of residuals
    sigma2 = SSR / df

    # Compute log-likelihood
    loglike_res = -0.5 * (len(Y) * tf.math.log(df * np.pi * sigma2) + SSR / sigma2)

    return loglike_res
 ```
````

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What log-likelihood do you want to calculate, Gaussian? What is the equation for that log-likelihood? How do the degrees of freedom factor into that log-likelihood calculation? $//$ It might be beneficial to give some equations along with the Python code. This is, after all, a venue for statistics, not programming. I did not vote to close but suspect such votes will occur if the whole question centers on Python debugging.

Comment: can you show us the statsmodel call, and ideally a dataset we can both use that shows us what parts don't match up?

Comment: The statsmodel call is like this: res = smf.ols(formula=full_formula, data=current_data).fit() and to find the log likelihood, I use res.llf.

Comment: The log likelihoods are way off. The one from statsmodel is -14.281920138266969 and from the code in the original question -68.72626

Comment: I only ask because it's very easy to forget to manually add an intercept in statsmodels. But anyways, logliks are only defined up to a constant, so it's not surprising that they differ. Try splitting the data into a couple different parts, evaluate loglike for TF and SM, and plot one vs the other to see if they form a line.

Comment: Ah ok, that good to know. Actually now that I checked, likelihood ratio computed from the log likelihoods of my full and nested models are almost the same with TF and SM, so code might work after all?

Comment: I suggest doing the plotting exercise and examining the slope of that line. If the slope has something to do with $\sqrt{2\pi}$ or the sample size, I think I know the culprit.

Comment: I did the plot you suggested, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N52nF.png . The shape is quite odd. I call here TF testing and SM baseline. The cols are log_likelihoods of full model

Comment: Hard to say exactly where things are drifting apart without reproducible code tho; maybe try using sigma2=SSR/N instead of SSR/df? But at a high level your TF code looks correct.

Comment: Since you're inverting $X^\top X$, accumulated numerical error is a potential sharp corner (because this squares the condition number). Solve the linear system with QR decomposition or SVD instead. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/qr

Comment: I could believe that `sigma2 = SSR` will yield a match, too, provided the neural network converges.

Comment: @Sycorax did you delete one of my comments? I did not realize high rep users were able to do that? Anyways yes for sure using tf.linalg.lstsq(X,y) will yield better results than direct matrix inversion (so, OP, replacing, the entire block commented by "Compute coefficients using TensorFlow
" with just "coefficients = tf.linalg.lstsq(X_with_bias, y)"). But I would wager that that is not the issue here.

Comment: @JohnMadden Because my comment was misguided, I deleted my comment and marked your reply as "no longer needed," since it replied to a comment that no longer existed. When a moderator marks a comment as "no longer needed," the software deletes it automatically.

Comment: @Sycorax thanks for taking the time to explain this; as an amateur sociologist of science I am interested in how scientific information is disseminated so I had to ask :)

Comment: @JohnMadden Yeah, there's no malicious intent here -- I'm not trying to conceal anything. The reason I removed it is that irrelevant comments are, at best, distracting and at worst frustrating for OP.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions! I tried sigma2=SSR/N and coefficients = tf.linalg.lstsq(X_with_bias, y), but they did not fix my problem. At least it seems my code does not have obvious errors in the statistics part, which I also wanted to confirm in this post, if by high level the idea looks correct. I'll continue to debug and see if I can find something.